# How can I install pipelight-multi on Ubuntu 17.04 to steam Silverlight videos?

Tags: firefox, 17.04, video-streaming, pipelight, moonlight

I have tried the following in order to install `pipelight-multi` so I can watch videos powered by Microsoft Silverlight (e.g HBO Now):

```
sudo apt-get install wine-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package pipelight is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'pipelight' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install `pipelight`? Or alternatively, how can I watch HBO Now on Ubuntu since all the posts on *Ask Ubuntu* either require installing `pipelight`, PlayOnLinux (buggy Firefox), or require using Hotstar? I have also looked at other post addressing `pipelight` installation issues, but they did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can install pipelight on Ubuntu 17.x. It isn't impossible, just tricky. These steppes worked for me, and now I can enjoy HBO from Ubuntu 17.10. Just open your terminal and type the following commands.

**Step 1:** *You need proper rights to do things. Type your password.*

```
sudo su
```

(If you have no proper rights to do this try the sudo command before every other command in the list.)

**Step 2:** *Add pipelight's repository.*

```
add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
```

**Step 3:** *Advanced Packaging Tool's update.*

```
apt-get update
```

**Step 4:** *Open the following directory.*

```
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

**Step 5:** *File listing.*

```
ls -l
```

*Now you should see a file in the list, named something like this:*

```
pipelight-ubuntu-stable*.list
```

**Step 6:** *Open the following file with nano or vi or whatever you like.*

```
nano pipelight-ubuntu-stable*.list
```

**Step 7:** *Change your Ubuntu's version everywhere in the text to xenial. In my case from artful to xenial. But it could be other, it depends on your Ubuntu's version.*

From one of these:
(16.10) yaketty,
(17.04) zesty,
(17.10) artful

To this:
(16.04) xenial

**Step 8:** *Save the edited file. If you are using nano, just press control+x.*

**Step 9:** *Install pipelight.*

```
apt-get install --install-recommends pipelight-multi
```

**Step 10:** *Pipelight's update.*

```
pipelight-plugin --update
```

**Step 11:** *Remove existing flash version. (Or other plugin versions which you want to install with pipelight.)*

```
apt-get remove adobe-flashplugin
```

**Step 12:** *Enable the necessary plugin.*

```
pipelight-plugin --enable flash
```

Or other plugins like:

```
pipelight-plugin --enable silverlight
```

and so on.

**Step 13:** *Pipelight's update to recognizes enabled plugin(s).*

```
    pipelight-plugin --update
```

**Step 14:** *Add the plugin(s) to firefox.*

```
pipelight-plugin --create-mozilla-plugins
```